# wrong number of arg for devise emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I havent experienced this before, but since moving my rails site to Heroku I have getting the following message whenever trying to trigger Devise to send an email

```
Started POST "/members/forgot-password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-24 00:02:27 +1100
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9G1P34ddbq2TN7SkmFuCet5d7fPMvWdSSpIaGqSZW9g=", "user"=>{"email"=>"paul.mcguane@*****"}, "commit"=>"Recover password"}
  User Load (3.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'paul.mcguane@me.com' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31ms

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (2 for 1):
  app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb:8:in `reset_password_instructions'
```

mailer.rb

```
    class Devise::Mailer < ::ActionMailer::Base
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

  def confirmation_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions)
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions)
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions)
  end
end
```

Comment: Which version of Rails / Devise you're running and there's any other dependency on your application to deal with the email delivery on Heroku?

Comment: ended up uninstalling the gem, and reinstalling seemed to fix it :S

Answer (score -3, accepted):

ended up uninstalling the gem, and reinstalling seemed to fix it :S

Answer (score 10):

It seems the [latest version](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb) requires an additional argument.
At least it does for my code.  Here's the working code from my custom mailer class.
Note the extra argument `action` for each method.

```
  class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

    def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
      @token = token
      devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
    end

    def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
      @token = token
      devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions, opts)
    end

    def unlock_instructions(record, token, opts={})
      @token = token
      devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions, opts)
    end

    # optional: this override method is from Devise::Mailers::Helpers
    def headers_for(action,opts={})
      …
    end

  end
```

Comment: Where to add this file?

Answer (score 3):

try this way, because 'Devise introducing an extra options parameter in a recent version' as mentioned in above answer

```
     def reset_password_instructions(record, opts={})
       devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions)
     end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to Devise introducing an extra options parameter in a recent version. I think you want something like:

```
class Devise::Mailer < ::ActionMailer::Base
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

  def confirmation_instructions(record, opts={})
    devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts={})
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions, opts={})
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions, opts={})
  end

  def headers_for(actions, opts={}
    # see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14698599/18706
  end

end
```

Comment: Where should i add this file?

Comment: app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb or similar

Comment: Well that path was directly from the OP question's output. I have it as UserMailer in app/mailers/user_mailer.rb. Make sure your mailer class begins with `include Devise::Mailers::Helpers`.

Comment: And note Webdevotion's answer pointed out this extra token arg.