# Argument Error (wrong number of Arguments) in Ruby on Rails duing integration of Devise and PostageApp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, arguments, postageapp

I'm a relatively newbie RoR hobby developer. I use Devise for user management and I'm planning to use PostageApp for sending "forget password" emails. The RoR version is 4.2.0.

I've configured PostageApp properly. And followed the instructions on PostageApp site. However, I keep getting a "wrong number of arguments" error.

**error message**

```
2015-11-16T15:01:07.785094+00:00 app[web.1]: MyDeviseMailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in 0.8ms
2015-11-16T15:01:07.785091+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-16T15:01:07.785415+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 597ms
2015-11-16T15:01:07.775613+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.5ms)  BEGIN
2015-11-16T15:01:07.781596+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.6ms)  COMMIT
2015-11-16T15:01:07.787783+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-16T15:01:07.787786+00:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)):
2015-11-16T15:01:07.787787+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb:13:in `reset_password_instructions'
```

**app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb**

```
class MyDeviseMailer < PostageApp::Mailer
include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

def confirmation_instructions(record)
# PostageApp specific elements (example):
postageapp_template 'my-signup-confirmation'
postageapp_variables :email => record.email,
:link  => confirmation_url(:confirmation_token => record.confirmation_token)

devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions)
end

def reset_password_instructions(record)
# PostageApp specific elements (example):
postageapp_template 'my-password-reset'
postageapp_variables :name => record.name ||= record.email,
:link => password_url(:reset_password_token => record.reset_password_token)

devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions)
end

def unlock_instructions(record)
# PostageApp specific elements (example):
postageapp_template 'my-unlock-instructions'
postageapp_variables :name => record.name ||= record.email,
:link => unlock_url(:unlock_token => record.unlock_token)
devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions)
end

protected
# Ensures template subject is used instead of the default devise mailer subject.
def headers_for(action)
headers = super
headers[:subject] = ‘’
headers
end
end
```

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
config.mailer = "MyDeviseMailer"
config.mailer_sender = '"Webmaster" <no-reply@mysite.com>'
require 'devise/orm/active_record'
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
config.reconfirmable = true
config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
config.password_length = 8..128
config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing only one of the required arguments to `reset_password_instructions` when it actually needs 3:

```
reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
```

Also, take a look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040844/wrong-number-of-arg-for-devise-emails) post

Comment: Also, use the `token` which  you get as a parameter, instead of `record.reset_password_token` in `password_url`.

Comment: Thank you Cyzanfar and Yogesh. Very helpful insights.

Answer (score 0):

When we are using devise we have to write below code with pass default aruguments

app/models/user.rb

```
  handle_asynchronously :send_reset_password_instructions
  handle_asynchronously :send_confirmation_instructions
  handle_asynchronously :send_on_create_confirmation_instructions
```

## Send Devise email with queuing process using delayed job active record gem

#Send confirmation email after creating new user

```
def send_on_create_confirmation_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.delay.confirmation_instructions(self, :confirmation_instructions, opts={})
  end
```

#Send reset password email

```
def send_reset_password_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.delay.reset_password_instructions(self, :reset_password_instructions, opts={})
  end
```

#send unlock email

```
def send_unlock_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.delay.unlock_instructions(self, :unlock_instructions, opts={})
  end
```