# send custom email to static email adress with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise

Ok, here is my question. Is it possible to send the custom email to a static email address using the devise. Here is my devise.rb:

```
config.mailer = "MyMailer"
```

Here is my my_mailer.rb:

```
 class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer

   default from: "email@example.com"


   def welcome_email

    mail(:to => 'myemail@hotmail.com', :subject => "New user!")
   end



 end
```

and here is my welcome_email.html.rb in views/my_mailer:

```
 <h1>New user just signed up! </h1>
```

I need this email to be sent to me at the same time when the devise sends confirmation instructions to the new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use make your own custom mailer:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer

Alternatively, you can define `headers_for` method in your devise resource:

```
def headers_for(action)
  {:bcc => 'email@example.com'}
end
```

Here's where you can get more info about `headers_for`:

[rails 3 + devise: how to modify the mailer method for confirmation emails to add user's second email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271093/rails-3-devise-how-to-modify-the-mailer-method-for-confirmation-emails-to-add)

Comment: But, now on heroku logs, I get that the email is sent, but there is no email in my inbox. Or is the delivery delayed for some reason?

Comment: What kind of email are you sending to? Gmail?